# Find which rows where foreign key constraint fail

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

While trying to add a foreign Key constraint to two very large tables, I get the error.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

This is usually due to some data in the primary table not present in the foreign table, normally I check for known anomalies like null values, out of range values etc, once these are taken care of, I can get the constraint satisfied. However this time the problem is more subtle.

What I want to know is there any way to query for all the rows which are causing the constraint to fail??

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Assuming you have following table, and FK relationship.

```
parent(parent_id (PK), name)
child(child_id, name, parent_id (FK));
```

You could find which rows are missing in `parent` table but exists in `child` table, using following `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT child.parent_id
FROM child LEFT JOIN parent ON child.parent_id = parent.parent_id
WHERE parent.parent_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: thanks..it works, i was trying something similar before i posted, but guess missed something..

Comment: @Manquer Thanks, you could accomplish using 3 different ways. `LEFT JOIN` (mine), `NOT IN` (Lumpy's), `NOT EXISTS`. but, I guess `LEFT JOIN` is faster than others.

Comment: I was just mentioning the same regarding speed to lumpy. I guess JOIN is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: @Manquer I agree with you ;-)

Comment: FWIW, this worked well on Oracle Database 12c (Rel. 12.2.0.1.0).

Answer (score 13):

The solution by InoS Heo will work. Here is another way.

```
SELECT *
FROM child
WHERE NOT key IN (
    SELECT key
    FROM parent
);
```

Of course `key` is the target field(s) you intend to put the constraint on later.

Comment: thanks.. your solution is simpler, but for my large table set it seemed slower